# Ajax Call coming up empty in views.py (Django)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am using Django and trying to call the following function in my .js file:

```
$.ajax({
        url : '/table',
        type : 'GET',
        data : {
          fields : 'fieldName'
          ,rows: 3
        }
    });
```

Below is the code in my `views.py` file:

```
def table(request):

    fields = request.GET["fields"]
    rows = request.GET["rows"]
    return render(request, 'nfl/table.html', {"rows": [[rows]], "finalFields": [fields]})
```

Below is my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^table/?$', views.table, name='table'),
]
```

The error I am getting is `MultiValueDictKeyError` at `/table`. And when I use `request.GET.get("fields")` instead, the render function works but `None` is the value of my `fields` and `rows`. It seems like the data from my ajax call is not getting passed to my `views.py` file, why is this?

Comment: I think it should be `POST` method instead of `GET`?

Comment: can we have a look at your URLs patterns? maybe you're not really calling that view with the url `/table`

Comment: what your `AJAX` is supposed to do? you are using `type : 'GET'`, but next defining some `data`, which should be used only with `POST`.

Comment: I want to open up a new window, (I have that functionality it's just not shown in the code above), and populate a table in there with fields and rows of data. The data will be passed as arrays for fields and arrays of arrays for rows but I can't get these simple data types to pass through now.

Comment: I have change "type: 'GET'" to "type: 'POST'" but I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: please check this you need the crsftoken for send data from ajax : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax